# Como saber o tempo restante para o alarme tocar

Tags: java, android, android-alarmmanager

Estou desenvolvendo um despertador. Abaixo eu tenho uma função para definir o alarme. Mas eu quero saber como encontrar o tempo restante para o AlarmManager acionar a PendingIntent.

Por exemplo, agora é 11:00 horas, e definimos o AlarmManager para acionar a PendingIntent 23:00 h, e pelos cálculos, nós sabemos que a PendingIntent será chamada daqui 12 horas. Mas como descobrir esse tempo restante?

Desde já agradeço a atenção

```
String schedule = "23:00"; //exemplo
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY, getTime(schedule));
cal.set(cal.MINUTE, getMinute(schedule));
cal.set(cal.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(cal.MILLISECOND, 0);

DateFormat dfH = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
DateFormat dfM = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
int currentTime = Integer.parseInt(dfH.format(new Date()));
int currentMinute = Integer.parseInt(dfM.format(new Date()));

Intent i = new Intent(context, RecebAlarm.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), id, i, 0);
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
long totalTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

if (currentTime > getTime(schedule) || (currentTime == getTime(schedule) && currentMinute >= getMinute(schedule))) {
    alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, totalTime + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
} else {
    alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, totalTime, pi); 
}
```

Comment: Pesquisando bem, parece que não existe um modo de consultar o `AlarmManager` os `PendingIntent` registrados nele. Provalvemente você terá que usar alguma forma persistente de guardar os alarmes que foram criados.

Comment: Eu estou guardando os dados usando o SQLite. 
_String schedule = "23:00";_ É só um exemplo, mas os alarmes são definidos pelo usuário. Eu estou tentando criar uma função para fazer esse cálculo, pois pelo que já vi, não tem nada pronto

Comment: Ah sim, você terá que converter para Calendar e fazer a aritmética. Existe a biblioteca `Joda Time` (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), que possui métodos que auxiliam nesse cálculo.

Comment: Vou dar uma estudada nessa biblioteca e vou ver se consigo fazer alguma coisa. De todo jeito, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Bom,  no caso mais simples de todos, você pode salvar num arquivo de preferências a hora configurada para o alarme despertar.

Assim, você tendo essa hora, basta subtraí-la da hora atual para descobrir o tempo restante.

Uma dica que lhe dou é trabalhar com a biblioteca [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Existem outras, mas tudo menos o Date nativo do Java, pois no Android existem alguns problemas que você ainda deve encontrar (se já não encontrou).

Em joda-time, basta fazer isso:

```
Hours.hoursBetween(LocalDateTime.now(), new LocalDateTime("hora do alarme no formato YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito te ter uma função que retorno a hora, minuto e segundo é a seguinte:

```
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
long diffHours = diff / (60 * (60 * 1000)) % 60;

String toLeave;
if (diffHours > 0) {
    toLeave = String.format("%dh %dm %ds", diffHours, diffMinutes, diffSeconds);
} else if (diffMinutes > 0) {
    toLeave = String.format("%dm %ds", diffMinutes, diffSeconds);
} else if (diffSeconds > 0) {
    toLeave = String.format("%ds", diffSeconds);
} else {
    return;
}
```

Onde `diff` é a diferença, em millisegundos, entre o tempo atual e o tempo que você configurou o alarme.